# In Drupal how to have Email account activation without admin approval and also a user set password?

Tags: email, drupal, authentication, activation

For my website, i want the user to confirm his email address(by clicking on the email-activation link in his/her mail) and only then be allowed to log in to his user account.
This happens perfectly well when a user's password is generated by drupal. But i want this to happen after using LogginToBoggan where user sets his own password. How do i do it?

Comment: In short ,user should not log in to his account until he has clicked the activation link in his email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at this module
http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan_prevent

Unfortunately, it has not been ported to Drupal 7 yet...

Comment: Thanks a lot DuaelFr ! I am using drupal 6 and it works exactly the way i want... !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, DuaelFr. The [LoginToboggan Prevent preauth](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan_prevent) module is available for Drupal 7 now.
And it realy does all the stuff. We can have "Email account activation without admin approval and also a user set password".

P.S. Don't forgot to uncheck 'Immediate login' option.

P.S.S. If you add user programmatically you may [use this cone](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15262/programmatic-user-registration-not-forcing-user-to-activate-account/31169#31169)